# Type of image to be added as the background of windows form gives better performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

which type of image to be added as the background of windows form gives better performance and reduce the loading time?
**JPEG or png**?

Comment: i wouldn't use pnp... i don't think it's supported

Comment: Sorry for the typing mistake.. its png

Comment: Having seen the tags, is this windows forms, or asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems pretty easy to test using the [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class. Your best bet is to test, my gut feeling says PNG, as jpeg would need to be decompressed. EDIT: So does PNG, so testing is definitely the way to go (i was confusing PNG with BMP).

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about loading time you better use jpeg as generally they are smaller in size.

Check this [link](http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/internet/2002/jpg_gif_png.asp). It gives more relevant information required for selecting an image type.

Comment: This advice applies to the internet, OP specified windows forms.

Comment: Having seen the tag [tag:asp.net], i think your answer might apply.